# ADD DYNAMIC attribute for category to accordion

Tags: categories, menus, javascript

i try to do category's accordion dynamic for show article with loop in WordPress i do it with static HTML and JQuery but i cant understand how i can add attr like data-class="" and  pass it to items

```
    <ul class="s3_accordion">
       <?php
    $categories = get_categories( array(
        'orderby'   => 'name',
        'order'     => 'DESC'
    ) );
    $cat_array = array();
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        $category_link = sprintf( 
            '<li class="artical_options" data-class=".%2$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</li>',
            esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
            esc_attr( sprintf( __( '%s', 'textdomain' ), $category->slug ) ),
            esc_html( $category->slug )
        );
        echo sprintf( esc_html__( '%s', 'textdomain' ), $category_link );
        $cat_array[] = $category->term_id;
    }
 ?>
</ul>
```

And Here The accordion Body :

```
<div class="col-lg-4 s3_shuffle_image">
                <div class="card">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"><a class="artical_options" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?PHP the_title(); ?> </a></h5>
                        <p class="card-text"> <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 100); ?> </p>
                        <div class="s3_shuffle_date">
                            <p>4 week ago | <a class="artical_options" href="<?php the_author_link() ?>"><?php the_author_nickname() ?> <i class="far fa-comment"></i></a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and here JQuery code :

```
$('.s3_accordion li').on('click', function () {
   $(this).addClass('s3_accordion_active').siblings().removeClass('s3_accordion_active');
        if($(this).data('class') === '.uncategorized') {
            $('.s3_shuffle_image').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.s3_shuffle_image').fadeOut();
            $($(this).data('class')).fadeIn();
        }
    });
```

all me need to know how i can use the_category() function or something else to add attr and pass it beside s3_shuffle_image class.

Thanks Tony for your awesome solution.

Comment: Can you show the code where you generate the HTML for the lists?

Comment: yes i had edit the post to more explain, thanks for replay

Comment: It still doesn't show how you generate the `<li>` tags.  If you show us the query and how it generates the mark-up we can help you get the category slug into the `data-class` attribute.

Comment: thanks Tony, actually I'm new in WordPress world i try with that. i put it in the post

Comment: Long Way, I answered for you.  I actually tested this on my own test site and it worked perfectly. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you were basically almost there, all you had to do was output the slug value in two places in the `sprint()`.

**Answer edited/added to:**

```
<ul class="accordion">
<?php
    $categories = get_categories( array(
        'orderby'   => 'name',
        'order'     => 'DESC',
        'offset'    => 1
    ) );
    $cat_array = array();
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        $category_link = sprintf( 
            '<li><a href="%1$s" data-class=".%2$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a></li>',
            esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
            esc_attr( sprintf( __( '%s', 'textdomain' ), $category->slug ) ),
            esc_html( $category->slug )
        );
        echo sprintf( esc_html__( '%s', 'textdomain' ), $category_link );
        $cat_array[] = $category->term_id;
    }
?>
</ul>

    <?php
    global $post;
    if( !empty( $cat_array ) ) :
        foreach( $cat_array as $cat ) :
            $category = get_term( $cat, 'category' );
            $cat_slug = $category->slug;
            echo '<div class="col-lg-4 s3_shuffle_image ' . $cat_slug . '">';
            $postslist = get_posts( array(
                'posts_per_page'    => 3,
                'cat'               => $cat,
            ) );
            if( $postslist ) :
                foreach( $postslist as $post ) :
                    setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <?php
                endforeach; 
                wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;
            echo '</div>';
        endforeach;
    endif;
    ?>
```

So in the line where you return the `<li>` formatted string (`sprint()`), you are simply adding your `data-class` attribute and repeating the token (`%2$s`) to the second item your returning.

You did also have an error on this line where you placed a period outside of the quotes so PHP tried to execute it instead of treating it as part of the string.

`esc_attr( sprintf( __( '%s',. 'textdomain' ), $category->slug         )),`

Please note that you should also match all instances of the generic `textdomain` with the actual `textdomain` of your theme... if you look in your `style.css` at the top you should see something like this:

```
/*
Theme Name: The Name of the Theme
Theme URI: http://domain.com
Author: your name or some other developer's name
Author URI: http://domain.com
Description: A description for the theme.
Version: 1.0 (updated version number)
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: LICENSE
Text Domain: make a custom text domain if there isn't one
Tags: custom-background, custom-logo, custom-menu, featured-images, translation-ready
*/
```

If the `Text Domain:` is there, make sure you're using that when you write other functions, if it's not there, add it and make it something unique. Fill out all those lines with something unique and accurate to your theme, keep the version number updated, etc.

To explain the *edit/addition*, what we're doing is, as we run the for each on all of the categories that were returned, we're adding them to an array we created before the for each: `$cat_array = array();`.  The last item in the `foreach()` now ads each category's ID to at the array: `$cat_array[] = $category->term_id;`

Then, inside the `s3_shuffle_image` div, we run a `foreach()` on the array we just created. Within that foreach we run a `get_posts()' function that calls for the 3 most recent posts of each category based on the ID.

Then, if that `get_posts()` query returns any results, we run another foreach and spit out the content/data from each of the returned posts inside of the accordion div.

**There are two issues I see. $cat_array is an array of IDs, not objects, so the ‘cat’ query arg should just be 'cat' => $cat,
The other is when you use setup_postdata( $post ), you must explicitly declare global $post;**

Comment: Tony, this is awesome solution thank you too much i understand it now and remove links to make it shuffle with other item categories.
`'<li><a href="%1$s" data-class=".%2$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a></li>'`
To
`'<li data-class=".%2$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</li>'`
But I need to know how i can add posts from this categories and give it class from slug to can accordion work like this :
`<div class="s3_shuffle_image">
    <div class="%2$s"><div>
</div>`

Comment: I updated my answer and wrote the code that will generate the list of `<div>` elements that will sit inside the container.  I don't know what you want to display from the posts though so you'll have to edit that part yourself, but for my example I put in the Title as a link and then the Excerpt.  If this answers your original question please remember to accept the answer.

Comment: yes sure is perfectly answer, 
**thank you hundred time again.**

Comment: You're very welcome, I went back and added a detailed explanation instead of just some code, that way you get a better understanding of what's happening.  Welcome to WordPress StackExchange.  :-)

Comment: Thanks Tony, this is very kind from you :)

Comment: sorry for bother you :( , but when try $cat_slug is empty value and i upload full section to see what i mean

Comment: Sorry, I missed a step... ...it's been a long day... ...I've updated my answer.  Basically, when we loop through the array of category IDs, we have to `get_term();` first then do the rest...

Comment: i hope you get good rest, now it's give the div slug class but there problem the post repeated 3 times and the same posts don't return the true value, if have some time try run code with your update i just put (accordion Body) to more explain. thanks for help